# ID out of sync in SharePoint-list after copy current item command in Sharepoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

Two lists have been created, the workflow for one of the list copies the current item to the other list.

When it copies over, the ID number is completely different.  This did work before, however through troubleshooting on previous issues I’ve deleted all the items in both lists a few times. This wouldn’t have made the ID’s out of sync, so why is this happening?

Comment: You can copy the old id to a new column...but not from id to id

Answer (score 0):

When we add a new item in the list, ID column will automatically be created. ID is a system field, you can't change it.

If you delete list items, and create new list item, the item Id will not reset to "1" automatically. As a workaround, we can save the list as a template and create new lists based on the template.

Or follow the article below to reset the list item ID.
http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/reset-list-item-id-in-sharepoint-2013-list-21294.aspx

Base on your requirement, I suggest you create a new field as the item "ID" and sync the two list base on the new "ID" field.